# SQL CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) gives same result for 2 different tables with similar content

Tags: sql, sql-server, checksum

I encountered something very strange in Microsoft SQL Server and basically it's something to do with the `CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))` function.

Let's say that I have 2 different tables where the content is like this: [image]

As you can see, each table only has 2 possible row contents:

- 103 | Thomas
- 112 | NULL

However, they're still different because the second table has 5 of these row combinations but if I try to calculate the `CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))` of the 2 tables by running

```
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) AS "Table 1 Checksum" FROM Table_1;
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))AS "Table 2 Checksum" FROM Table_2;
```

They will display the same result:

[image: 2 Tables with same CHECKSUM_AGG result]

This is very weird and I don't know why this is happening. I'm doing the `CHECKSUM_AGG` function to see if 2 tables have the same content and so far it looks like it's working quite well. However, in such rare cases where the 2 tables have similar content like those two above ^^, I'm afraid that the function will return the same result for the 2 tables.

Can someone please explain the reason behind this and if there's any way to mitigate this issue?

Thanks in advance and I would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

`BINARY_CHECKSUM` is checking if the values are the same but doesn't consider the number of times a value might occur on one table compared to the other. If the number of times the value occur is important and you wanted to detect there not the same because though they have the same values one table does have more entires of the values then the other, you can use `HASHBYTES` to detect there difference.

> BINARY_CHECKSUM satisfies the properties of a hash function: when applied >over any two lists of expressions, returns the same value if the corresponding >elements of the two lists have the same type and are equal when compared >using the equals (=) operator.

Example

```
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) AS "Table 1 Checksum",
HashBytes('md5',convert(varbinary(max),(SELECT * FROM Table_1 FOR XML AUTO))) AS "Table 1 Hashbytes",
 FROM Table_1;

SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*))AS "Table 2 Checksum",
HashBytes('md5',convert(varbinary(max),(SELECT * FROM Table_2  FOR XML AUTO))) AS "Table 2 Hashbytes",
FROM Table_2;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks so much for the reply @vvv4d. Hmmm, I tried it it looks like it's outputting some kind of hexadecimal values for each row. I'll look into this a bit more if I have the time. Gonna be honest with you, I'm a newbie in SQL so yeah, still learning. I'm also looking into triggers because apparently that's the proper way to see whether or not a table has ben modified instead of using hash/checksum. Thanks heaps man!